# Spring IDE version of eclipse won't allow me to install the Eclipse Market Place

Tags: eclipse, spring-ide

i recently download the Spring IDE complete download rather than download eclipse and plugin.

Hence now i goto the Update Sites and there is nothing there... so i add the following

http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/indigo/

which is noted here http://www.eclipse.org/mpc/

and try and install the market but i get the following error

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Marketplace Client
>   1.1.1.I20110907-0947 (org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group 1.1.1.I20110907-0947)   Missing requirement: Marketplace Client 1.1.1.I20110907-0947 (org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group 1.1.1.I20110907-0947) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.feature.feature.group
>   [1.0.0.v201004,2.0.0)' but it could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
Update eclipse first using Help->Check for Updates. 
Then try installing the market place
client.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on following link, without needing to update eclipse:
http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Studio-for-Android/Missing-Eclipse-Marketplace/td-p/22944

Essentially I had to (re)enable the checkbox: "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"
and then just selected the latest version if the Client without the source package.